# MPMoviePlayerController doesn't play local Videos

Tags: ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to play a video by MPMoviePlayerController in iOS 6.0 by two methods.

1. Right after camera captures it and
2. From Camera Roll

Here is the snippet for it.

```
-(void) playMovie
{
  self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
  [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
  [self.moviePlayer setContentURL:self.movieURL];
  self.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
  [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake ( 0, 0, 320, 476)];

  [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.moviePlayer];

  [self.moviePlayer play];
}
```

I tried taking the property `moviePlayer` as both strong and retain but no use.
My problem is very much similar to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602899/mpmovieplayercontroller-breaks-stops-after-going-to-fullscreen-in-ios6), that the video stops within one second. However if you are playing a video which is over internet it works fine.

Here is the [Git Source Code](https://github.com/grsomani/CameraClick) for What I have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue with this.

I am using this for iPad hence I use a `UIPopoverController` to select video from library and after selection is done I dismiss the popover in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` and call the function `playMovie` (written above)

The problem here was if dismiss popover the moviePlayer is also removed.

Though I didn't get why this happened, I wrote a work around for this by saving the URL path globally and adding an additional play button to start the movie after dismissing the popover. The complete code is [here](https://github.com/grsomani/CameraClick)

Answer (score 1):

Try to intialise `self.moviePlayer` like this

```
  self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:contentPath]];

//contentPath is your movie file path
```

Comment: have tried this too.. Didn't work... You can have a look at my github code in function `playMovie`